# Swift: adding / removing observers in init / deinit raise error in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift

I've a simple swift UI component (https://github.com/mbigatti/BMXCircularButton) that is inspectable. In the `init` / `deinit` methods I have calls to start and stop the observation of the highlighted state.

```
init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "highlighted", options: .New, context: nil)
}

init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "highlighted", options: .New, context: nil)
}

deinit {
    self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "highlighted")
}
```

Doing this raise errors the Interface Builder with the following errors:

```
file:///Users/max/Progetti/StatusApp/CircularButton/CircularButton/View.xib: error: 
Live Views: Failed to update auto layout status: Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool raised a "NSRangeException" 
exception: Cannot remove an observer <_TtC17BMXCircularButton14CircularButton 0x10ba98e00> 
for the key path "highlighted" from <_TtC17BMXCircularButton14CircularButton 0x10ba98e00> because it is not registered as an observer.

file:///Users/max/Progetti/StatusApp/CircularButton/CircularButton/View.xib: error: 
Live Views: Failed to render instance of _TtC17BMXCircularButton14CircularButton: Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool raised a "NSRangeException" 
exception: Cannot remove an observer <_TtC17BMXCircularButton14CircularButton 0x10bd055d0> 
for the key path "highlighted" from <_TtC17BMXCircularButton14CircularButton 0x10bd055d0> because it is not registered as an observer.
```

It could be a bug or I'm missing something?

Comment: Since it's on `self`, can't you just override the property and add a `willSet` or `didSet`?

Comment: There's an example of the preferred way to do this below.  I don't see anything off-hand in your code here, how are you creating instances of `BMXCircularButton`?

Comment: I suddenly see this in objective-c too in Xcode 7 beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by Kevin, the best answer here is really to use didSet and/or willSet in your class override since you're adding an observer to self.

```
override var highlighted:Bool {
    didSet {
        // Put your observerValue like code here
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution actually fixes the issue of observing the highlighted attribute but it is still unclear if `addObserver` / `removeObserver` are allowed in `init` / `deinit`.

Comment: Please note that this won't work for NSManagedObjects, because they won't allow `didSet` and `willSet`